# Buffering with PutS3Object

Tags: apache-nifi

My simplified Nifi setup is: ConsumeKafka_2_0 Processor into PutS3Object processor. I'm reading multiple topics and the topic name is being included in the S3 key prefix.
This works fine, but every FlowFile is being stored in a separate S3 object.

How can I accumulate some FlowFiles per topic? I came across the MergeContent processor, but I'm not sure, if it satisfies all my requirements.
S3 objects should be written

- after some amount of time, say 10 mins
- after some size threshold, say 100MB (whatever occurs first)
- in order

Bin-packing algorithm can merge FlowFiles in the wrong order, right? Defragment didn't seem to work, but I don't know, if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ControlRate processor?

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ControlRate/.

Try combining ControlRate processor with MergeContent processor may solve your particular use case.

If you want your flowfiles to be processed in a particular order, you may define it in the inbound Queue. I have attached a Screenshot so that "FirstInFirstOutPrioritizer" is selected.[image]